# Power BI - How to find total pbix size of all your reports in the workspace

Tags: powerbi

Is there anyway that I can find the total pbix size of all my reports in the Power BI workspace? Please let me know if that's possible!

Answer (score 2):

You can find out the total size of your reports in 2 ways.

1 - Go to the 'My Workspace' workspace, and clicking on the cog/gear icon in the top right corner and the option for Manage My Storage. That will give you a break down of the total sizes of your items. That will be across all workspaces you have deployed.

[image]

2 -For your items deployed in just one workspace, you can go to the selected workspace, select the gear icon and then select the 'Manage Group Storage' that will give you a breakdown of the size of the items. Yours will be in the 'Owned By Us' the rest should be in the owned by others.

[image]

Full details can be found on the MS Docs website [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-manage-your-data-storage-in-power-bi)